# How can I set accessibility options on an Android ROM without them?

Tags: android-10, accessibility, automotive-head-unit

After buying an Android '13'<sup>†</sup> Head unit with a screen higher resolution than my previous stereo, I found that it didn't offer any options to change the font or icon size in it's accessibility options, so text is too small at arms length, where the screen is.

Since there are no after market ROMs for this device yet, I wonder if there is any other way to change these settings via an app, or by editing a configuration file somewhere?

I have enabled Developer options on this device and can enable `adb` if needed.

<sup>† About may say "Android 13", but it's probably a lie, it looks more like Android 10, but I would like to know the most reliable way to work it out.</sup>

Comment: Do you have adb access?

Comment: Some of those settings for me have been in "Display" under "Display size and text" rather than Accessibility, have you looked there? 

Also, would you mind providing the Android version? A lot probably depends on at least that.

Comment: Nothing like that in Display either. What's the most accurate way to tell what version it it, as it's one of those versions hacked to say that it's Android 13, when it definitely isn't. I believe that it's based on Android 10, but I don't know which values in About that I can trust, and which I cant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# for font size
adb shell settings put system font_scale 1.10
# 1.30 is apparently the largest font size possible
# for dpi
adb shell wm density <dpi> # higher the value, larger the icons
```

Sometimes a reboot might be needed for changes to take place